# How to display output after entering some integers separated by a newline without the use of arrays?

Tags: c, input, while-loop

Task:

> `t` denotes the number of inputs, followed by `t` lines, each containing a single integer `n`.
>   For each integer `n` given at input, display a line with the value of `n`.
>
> **Sample input:**
>
> ```
> 4
> 1
> 2
> 5
> 3
> ```
>
> **Sample output:**
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 5
> 6
> ```

The output should appear after all lines of integer `n` are taken as input, i.e, it should not display output after each line of input.

How can this be done using a `while` loop without the use of array to store the input numbers?

```
while(i<t)
{
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("%d",&num);
    i++;
}
```

This code is working fine if the input numbers `n` are separated by a space and appears on the same line. But when the input numbers are provided after a newline, it displays the corresponding output after each input value.

Comment: How is `1 2 3 5 3` equal to `1 2 3 5 6`?

Comment: Such testcases are only used for testing the output to match the expected output. So you need not worry about the ordering. Try using a command prompt and check. It works fine.

Comment: You are _unlucky_ if that code worked. `printf("%d",&num);` should be `printf("%d",num);`

Comment: use linked list instead of array.

Comment: use file instead of array.

Comment: I am not a beginner..know every DS very well.. it was just about finding an easier and better way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally such type of input output are used in coding competition where a user is expected to match the expected output to the actual output.

Try pasting the input using a command prompt or online [compilers](http://ideone.com/vpBFzo) and check it. It is totally fine as the output is as expected.

How does it take if the total input is given at once.

First it reads the `t` and then it reads the `num` and prints the number but your printing is actually after the input. This is how the output is checked in a coding competition.

PS: If you want everything after input, use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to this without using array, then the best way i could think of is recursion. But note, that internally, your values will be stored in the stack frames, and your values will be printed in reverse(because stack is LIFO). Here is how you can do,

```
void foo(i, t)
{
    if(t==i)
        return;
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);

    foo(++i, t);

    printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

Note, however, that the values will be printed in reverse, as `stack` is LIFO